# How can I set HTML string in DOM and bind to an object?

Tags: html, angular, bind

I have markup like this in my angular html component template:

```
<div *ngIf="htmlTemplate && jsonObj" [innerHTML]="htmlTemplate"></div>
```

I have my `jsonObj` variable coming from an endpoint as:

```
{ firstname: 'Dave' }
```

and my `htmlTemplate` string variable coming from an endpoint as:

```
<strong>Hi....{{firstname}}</strong>
```

So far, I have managed to get the `htmlTemplate` rendering in the page, using the [innerHTML] binding, but it's not doing the bind + replacement with the model value from the JSON object.

**Q) Is there a way I can make Angular take this html + json obj and render it?**

Comment: please can you remove the duplicate flag + comment? I've deleted the other question.

Answer (score 0):

The string output by `htmlTemplate` will not be interpolated by Angular once it is part of the page. So if the sting is `<strong>Hi....{{firstname}}</strong>` that is exactly what you will see on the page, including the {{ firstname }} part.

You will need to set the variable in the code file when the result comes from the endpoint:

```
this.htmlTemplate = `Hello...${result.data.firstname}`
```

Change this as appropriate for the structure of your returning data.

So the string is, for example, `Hello... Dave`.